# Automatic confirmation of deletion in powershell

Tags: scripting, powershell, windows-vista, automation

I'm running the following command:

```
get-childitem C:\temp\ -exclude *.svn-base,".svn" -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

Which prompts me very frequently like this:

```
Confirm
The item at C:\temp\f\a\d has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue,
all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

How can I have it automatically set to "A"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try using the `-Force` parameter on `Remove-Item`.

Comment: please see below answers for a more comprehensive answer to this problem.

Answer (score 71):

The default is: **no prompt.**

You can enable it with `-Confirm` or *disable* it with `-Confirm:$false`

However, it will still prompt, when the target:

- is a directory
- *and* it is not empty
- *and* the `-Recurse` parameter is not specified.

`-Force` is required to also remove hidden and read-only items etc.

**To sum it up:**

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
```

...should cover all scenarios.

Comment: So if you want it to delete but not delete, and just raise an error when it's a directory you also have to test for it being a directory separately.

Comment: @WarrenP What behavior exactly are you looking for? If you tell PowerShell to delete a directory, it will delete it. Unless it's not empty, then the behavior will be as described.

Answer (score 35):

Add **-confirm:$false** to suppress confirmation.

Comment: This WILL NOT work.  -Confirm is for forcing confirmation.  Having it off just runs the normal decision logic.

Comment: do you use -force -confirm:$false  ?

Answer (score 11):

Add -recurse after the remove-item, also the -force parameter helps remove hidden files
e.g.:

gci C:\temp\ -exclude *.svn-base,".svn" -recurse | %{ri $_ -force -recurse}

Comment: `-recurse` prevents confirmation for removing non empty folders. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
Remove-Item .\foldertodelete -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional tip:
Let's say the PS1 (helloworld.ps1) has a code like below:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Confirm:$false -Force
Write-Host "Hello, World!"
```

And if we expect that each time the code runs, it would automatically run the Set-ExecutionPolicy without prompting the user & run the code silently...

It won't work that way!! I'm still figuring out how to run a PS code without prompting the user & will post the solution if I find out

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `/A` behind the line.

Example:

```
get-childitem C:\temp\ -exclude *.svn-base,".svn" -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname} /a
```